# Rotate transform on Transformed bitmap does not consistently rotates

Tags: wpf, bitmap, rotation, rotatetransform

I have an image source that I convert to a transformed bitmap and add a rotate transform for rotation. I have this code via mouse double click. My problem is, sometimes it rotates, sometimes it doesn't (Visually). I put a break point on the mouse click, and I'm sure that it executes the code inside every time I perform a double click. By the way, I'm saving the angle that I use for the rotation that's why when I reload the image and put the saved angle on a render transform inside the image. It rotates to the saved angle.

Here's the code that I am using.

```
var dropCanvas = _dropTarget as ItemsControl;
                var obj = _baseImage.Tag as FloorObjectViewModel;

                var floorItem = (dropCanvas.ItemsSource as BindingList<FloorObjectViewModel>).ElementAt((dropCanvas.ItemsSource as BindingList<FloorObjectViewModel>).IndexOf(obj));
                floorItem.Angle += 90;
                if (floorItem.Angle > 360)
                {
                    floorItem.Angle = 0;
                }


                TransformedBitmap transformBmp = new TransformedBitmap();
                transformBmp.BeginInit();
                transformBmp.Source = _baseImage.Source as BitmapSource;

                RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
                rotateTransform.CenterX = _baseImage.ActualWidth / 2.0;
                rotateTransform.CenterY = _baseImage.ActualHeight / 2.0;
                rotateTransform.Angle = floorItem.Angle;

                transformBmp.Transform = rotateTransform;
                transformBmp.EndInit();

                _baseImage.Source = transformBmp;
```

I want to make it rotate every time I double click it. But it seems something was still executing on background when I perform a double click right after a first double click. (Sorry for being redundant, I hope you guys got my problem)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to write instead of `floorItem.Angle = 0` `floorItem.Angle -= 360` in the if condition. Seems current code is incorrect.

Comment: Not really sure what difference does it makes. But I gave it a try and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Cause if angle is 360+90 = 450 it changes to 0 and rotation will not work.. (should reproduce in 1 of 4 cases)

Comment: I see. That might help with the logic. But sadly, even if the angle is less than 360, sometimes the rotation does not work.

Comment: You are reusing the previous (already transformed) TransformedBitmap in `_baseImage.Source` for the Source of the new TransformedBitmap, so transform will add up. Better keep the original BitmapSource without transformation.